# Fulltext search vely slow

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database like this

```
DATABASE

warehouse_folders
folder_id
folder_box_id
folder_number
folder_title
folder_content
folder_notes

warehouse_folder_value
folder_value_id
folder_value_folder_id
folder_value_01
folder_value_02
folder_value_03
folder_value_04
folder_value_05
folder_value_06
folder_value_07
folder_value_08
folder_value_09
folder_value_00
folder_value_11
folder_value_12

warehouse_box
box_id
box_number
box_description
```

**and about 40.000 lines.
All field are varchar and I have created Indexes for all.

I'm like to perform a fulltext search (PHP and MySQL_), but when add JOINS database stop responding.

Any help to solve?**

```
QUERY

SELECT
*

FROM
warehouse_folders

LEFT JOIN
warehouse_folder_value ON folder_value_id = folder_id

LEFT JOIN
warehouse_boxes ON box_id = folder_box_id



WHERE
(

(`box_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`box_description` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_title` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_content` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_notes` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_01` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_02` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_03` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_04` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_05` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_06` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_07` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_08` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_09` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_10` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_11` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
(`folder_value_12` LIKE '%".$search."%')

)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `like` operator does not perform fulltext search, it does simple patter matching. It is the [match(...) against(...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) operator which does fulltext searches, but you should create fulltext index to support such searches.
2. like "%constant%" searches cannot use indexes, since the pattern could fit at any part of the text within a field.
3. Mysql uses a single index for a table in a query. With `or` condition it could potentially use an index for 1 of the fields in the operation, not all of them. You could rewrite the where condition to use union instead of or - but as long as the patter has that leading wildcard, it is no use.

The above combined causes your sql query to be slow. You can verify the above using an explain, which will no doubt show full table scan.

Depending on your exact needs, a conversion to fulltext index and fulltext search, or the implementation of some external fulltext search solutions could improve your performance.